# Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) in TextView in XML

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, xml-parsing

This is my XML code, please tell me where I am doing wrong and please tell me how should I remove this error?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/dob"
<TextView                     **error is coming here in text view**
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="@string/cd" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/bd" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/Result" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

please tell me where I am doing wrong and please tell me how should I remove this error?

Comment: Your `Button` element isn't being closed.

Comment: omg it was  so simple error!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:text="@string/dob">
</button>

<TextView                     
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
android:text="@string/cd" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
android:text="@string/bd" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:text="@string/Result" />

</RelativeLayout>
```